# Visual components explorer

Tags: c#, winforms

Trying to design form by placing `Panel` on it and `RichTextBox` on the top of `Panel`. Is there any explorer that shows that `RichTextBox` is owned by `Panel` and not by `Form`?

I need to know who owns each component.

Comment: `Document outline` window, Ctrl+Alt+T

Comment: I'm using winforms

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you tell us more about what you mean by an "explorer"?

Comment: I need to know who owns each component.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on RichTextBox and in the context menu that opens (in middle part of it), assuming names are richTextBox1, panel1, form1 there are menu items as:

Select 'richTextBox1'

Select 'panel1'

Select 'form1'

[image]

That shows richtextbox1 is contained in panel1, ...
if richtextbox were inside the form the menu items would be like:

Select 'richTextBox1'

Select 'form1'

In runtime, you can simply do this:

```
Control c = RichTextBox1;
while(c.Parent!=null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(c.Name);
    c = c.Parent;
}
```